# Row to Column values with formatting in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have an `excel data source` which has Account related information columns include Account Name, Account Market, etc. In Power-Bi, the requirement is to show the Each Account account row values as showing in the reference image below.

[image]

I tried to use Multi-Card visual And got below structure

[image]

Here, column names ( `category labels` in the card visual) coming to bottom and the `hyperlinks` are not working. Do we have `any other visual` which will give expected output as in reference image or any formatting we can do using `dax`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately cards are not interactive, so you can't use links or any type of drill functionality within the card. You may be able to reformat the links into text to get them to show up on the card. You could also use a 1x1 matrix and simulate a card for each element which would allow you to use links and drills.

Comment: StelioK  Could you share if you have any links to workout above scenario?

Comment: I do not, it's something I've done to get around this. It's kind of a hack but it works, just not as pretty. You just use the matrix visualization and limit the rows and columns to one, so you are left with a single cell which you treat as a card.